# i have a table that come from .txt file and i need to find min and max

Tags: python

I have a function that makes a table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Name  |     A      |     B     |     C      |    D     |    E      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |    1.0     |    2.0    |    3.0     |   4.0    |   5.0     |
|  2   |    6.0     |    7.0    |    8.0     |   9.0    |   0.0     |
|  3   |    1.1     |    2.2    |    3.3     |   0.1    |   0.3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After that I need to ask the user what they need to do, either get the minimum or maximum. After that I need to ask if they want to do min through row or column and so far I can get the min of row 1 but I when I try to do row 2 or any column it still give me back the same value for row 1.

```
def minimum(y,l):
    for y in l:
        if y == 1:
            i= 0
            w=(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
            a= min(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
        elif y == 2:
            i = 5
            w=(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
            a= min(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
        return a


def menu(x,l): 
    if x == 1:
        make_table(l)
    if x == 2:
        y = input("enter a row (as a number) or a column (as an uppercase letter)")
        if y in [ '1','2','3']:
            mini = minimum(y, l)
            print("Minimum is:", mini)
    if x == 3:
        print ('bye')
```

I need a help on min then I can work the same way for max, thank you

Comment: `minimum(y, l)` defines y but then in `for y in l:` you reassign to it

Comment: Another issue is you `return` in the `for` loop, so it only ever does the first iteration before quiting the function.

Comment: i see what you mean but if i cant return outside of loop because if i try to get out of loop it gives me a indent error.thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def minimum(y,l):
    a = 0
    for y in l:
        if y == 1:
            i= 0
            w=(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
            a= min(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
        elif y == 2:
            i = 5
            w=(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
            a= min(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])
    return a
```

What would you do if the user input's 3? You haven't accounted for that case yet.

Comment: i am a beginner and don't know how to do matrix and pass than in a function.

Comment: thank you and i will put another elif and try to get the min out of that but hey this is still giving me the same answer for the both row 1 an 2 just like before, thank you so much i have done all of other work and i got stuck over here and have no clue to go forward.

Comment: A couple of follow-up questions then:

Why create variable w when it's not reference in the if statement?

What is the value of l?

Comment: I to locate the index of the list and i had a issue when i try to do min of a it gave me some issue and i assign with W and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store your values in a numpy 2d array?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(l).reshape(3,5)
minByCol = np.amin(a, axis=0) #array([ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0.1,  0. ])
minByRow = np.amin(a,axis=1)  #array([ 1. ,  0. ,  0.1])
```

Edit:
Since you can't import anything, I assume this is some kind of arbitrary homework problem.

I'm not inclined to do your homework for you, but here are some ideas. Why don't you take a slice instead of the awkward `a=min(l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2],l[i+3],l[i+4])` you could have `a = min(l[i:i+5])`

And instead of taking cases and manually setting the value of `i` for each case, why not set the value of `i` based on the value of `y` and then you can get rid of the `if` statements. In the case of a table with 5 columns, going by row you would have `i = (y-1)*5`

Comment: i am not allowed to use import, i have to use function and use a min max function. thank you for the help

Comment: but when i try to do a = min(l[i:i+5]) it gives me an error, cant assign int with str

Comment: I don't understand why you have ints or strings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact that you can call `min` or `max` with a list as argument?

Assuming your data is something like:

```
l= [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
    [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 2.2, 3.3, 0.1, 0.3]]
```

If the user want the min of row y, you just have to call `min(l[y-1])` (that is if your rows are numbered from 1)

Now if the user want the min of a colum, it's a little more difficult (but just a little)

- First you have to get the index from the letter. The `ord` function convert char to int. "A" is 65, so to get the column index, call `index = char(letter)-65`.
- Then you need to transpose the rows and colum of your original data. The `zip` function will help you do just that.

So:

```
index = char(letter) - 65
transpo = zip(*l)
print min(transpo[index])
```